# How to know where usage in Google Cloud APIs & Services comes from

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm getting a lot of traffic and errors in Google Cloud APIs & Services graph. When I hover it says it's "compute", but I'm not using the Compute service. I'm using other services like Google Cloud Functions, Google Cloud Run and Google Cloud Build.

Any ideas on how to find out where does it come from?

[image: Google Cloud APIs & Serivices traffic graph]
[image: Google Cloud APIs & Services errors graph]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be triggering because cloud functions use compute for allocating virtual resources such as VM to meet the architectural demand. Besides there could be firewall related activity/ health check services which is also handled by compute. for an elaborate view please follow following :

1. Scroll below Traffic graph and you will come across below[image]
2. Select the API/service you wish to explore, you will arrive to the image below.
3. Click on view metrics in lower right
   [image]
4. Either click on view metrics in lower right corner on the graph or simply click metrics menu on navigation pane on left.[image]

You will be able to view elaborated traffic response and error types triggering in your traffic. Hope it helps.